# Sony xperia m4 aqua memory

Tags: sony-xperia

I would like to ask if there is a way to bypass limitations of internal memmory delegated for applications as my mobile operator I bought phone from added some useless bloatware which after removing apps that were possible to remove brings me only to 1.8GB of space for applications.

As I would really like to play some of new games which have size of additional data as big as 500MB it is impossible to have many applications installed, because all data is stored into internal memory instead of memory card.

Reason is, application partition in internal memory is mounted as /storage/sdcard and external sd card is mounted as /storage/sdcard1

Because of this, there is no way to move applications to sd card (only manually, but they cant find their data, because they defaultly search in /storage/sdcard mountpoint) as it will move them just to other partition of internal memory.

My question is, is it possible to bypass this problem without actually rooting phone? Will there be software udate that will change method of mounting or solve it in some other way (like creating symbolic links to external card as data folder of application)?

Comment: This probably can't be done without root. It's a system limitation based on security considerations. If you are willing to root, I can probably help you. There is no way to change mountpoints without root.

Comment: Well, I might try to root it, but it would be really good if I made a rom backup 1st. My bootloader is locked, but its status is unlockable. Problem is, I dont have code.

Comment: Rooting is the way to do a rom backup. You can also use factory images.

Comment: I'll put up some terminal code for you to enter once you root.

Comment: I have custom rom from operator (Orange) full of bloatware, so with root I would be able to delete it right? Also, is it possible to unroot it and restore back to original state as I bought it? Just in case I would need to use warranty service.

Comment: Fastboot your phone. Boot, not flash, a custom recovery before rooting. Use the Nandroid backup option. Copy the resulting backup somewhere safe. Now, flash the custom recovery, root, and delete the bloatware apps right from the system/app directory. No root uninstaller apps required. In case you still want to change the mountpoints, I'll have some terminal code ready for you.

Comment: To make Nandroid backup, do I need custom bootloader? Because my original one is locked and I dont have unlock code for it. Or is there a way to flash it with custom one without unlocking it?

Comment: I can't help you on this. You can try out XDA for unlocking your bootloader. There is nothing called a custom bootloader for your device.

Comment: It appears as if your device is very difficult to root currently. However, you are welcome to try my method. It technically isn't supposed to require root, but lollipop has some issues with symlinking on unrooted devices.

Comment: i dont really need to link obb files tho, but data of applications (new games, converter and such) so will try to soft link their folders to sdcard1. Hope it will work from adb shell

Comment: On the contrary, you need to link the obb files, they are the extra days you were talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following commands in a terminal emulator after you have rooted and installed busybox:

```
su
ln -s /storage/sdcard1/Android/obb/ /storage/sdcard/Android/obb/
```

Copy the games extra data (`.obb`) files to `Android/obb/` folder on your SD card from your computer. This may or may not work with games downloaded from Google Play, I have not tested it.

Comment: Using this command gives me permission denied. Looks like root is the only option to fix this problem. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: You can upvote comments and answers. Please contribute.